.authenticated() is not working as expected
Here am giving authorization for certain links and links that should work only after authentication.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
                    var corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
                    corsConfig.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
                    corsConfig.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTION"));
                    corsConfig.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                    corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    return corsConfig;
                }))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login/**")
                                .permitAll().anyRequest()
                                .authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailsService());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


}

when I use this url http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/auth/login/create it works without authentication
My expectation is that http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/auth/login/create should only work when the user has logged in.

Why? YOu specified it as permitAll so why should it work only when logged in.

I used permitAll to give access to the links after /login and why links should work only for the authenticated user after /login is because I used authenticated() @M. Deinum.

i dont understand what you are saying but .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login/**").permitAll() means that all subpaths beneath /login are permitted without authentication. that includes /login/create

I tried to remove permitAll and kept only authenticated, but that also didn't help

Ok to make it simple I want only authenticated users who logged in to get access to the links following with /login/**

/api/v1/auth/** matches everything below so the /api/v1/auth/login/** rule is useless as it is going to be ignored. As mentioend in the documentation the order of rules is important. THe order they are defined in is the order they are consulted in and the first one found is the one that is matched.

So if am not mistaken basically /api/v1/auth/** interferes with /api/v1/auth/login/** right ?
If that’s the case then I’ll try to change the endpoints for /api/v1/auth/** @M.Deinum

As stated the order is important. If you switch the order it will work.  Remember that .anyRequest().authenticated() needs to be last! as anyRequest means /** which will always match so if you put that first.... If you add /api/v1/auth/login/** before the /api/v1/auth/** it will match earlier and be applied.

Solved the problem: The issue was that the security context  was setting the authentication even if the token is invalid.

Solved the problem: The issue was that the security context was setting the authentication even if the token is invalid.
here
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final static String BEARER_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    private final static String HEADER_NAME = "Authorization";

    private final JwtService jwtService;

    private final UserService userService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request,@NonNull HttpServletResponse response,@NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        var authHeader = request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(authHeader) || !StringUtils.startsWith(authHeader,BEARER_PREFIX))
        {
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            return;
        }

        var jwt = authHeader.substring(BEARER_PREFIX.length());
        var username = jwtService.extractUserName(jwt);

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(username) && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null)
        {
            UserDetails userDetails = userService.
                    userDetailsService().
                    loadUserByUsername(username);

            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt,userDetails))
            {
                SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                securityContext.setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
};

